# Rendering a WMTS image inside of OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I'm trying to enable a WMTS inside of OpenLayers. The code I have so far:

```js
theurl = var thewmts =  new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: 'http://localhost:2222/geoserver/wmts'
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });
```

Then to add a layer would it be something like:

```js
var trailheads = new ol.layer.Image({
          source: new ol.source.ImageWMTS({
          url: theurl,
          params:{'LAYERS': 'CAICWeb:trailheads'}
        })
});
```

Comment: Your code won't work. See OL WMTS example: https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html?q=wmts

Comment: so i would have to call the WMTS capabilities script src in the head section ?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can construct WMTS layer source options yourself, but it's a bit more complicated, see https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/wmts.html?q=wmts

Comment: so that example gives how to do it from an existing WMTS server. How would i go about doing it on my server like https://localhost:2222/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?service=WMTS&request=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&layer=CAICWeb:' + layerName + '&format=image/jpeg&TileMatrixSet=EPSG:3857(LZ)&TileMatrix=EPSG:900913:{z}&TileRow={y}&TileCol={x}'